# Downloading an attachment

Tags: vb.net

I used this to download an attachment, the file is downloading but the original content is not there,the content is just showing like `System.Byte[]`

```
Protected Sub DownloadFile(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim id As Integer = Integer.Parse(TryCast(sender, LinkButton).CommandArgument)
    Dim bytes As Byte()
    Dim fileName As String, contentType As String
    strQry = "select file_name, license_doc, file_type from Driver_Mas where Id=" & Val(id)

    Reader = Osql.ExecuteRead(strQry)
    While Reader.Read

        bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Reader.Item("license_doc"))

        contentType = Reader.Item("file_type").ToString()
        fileName = Reader.Item("file_name").ToString()



        Response.Clear()
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Response.ContentType = contentType
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName)
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you check the database to see if it contain the right value? Do you have an other program that download the file (maybe that program isn't working)?  Btw: the sample is uploading not downloading

Comment: is the attachment a string or numeric value?

Answer (score 0):

Following code gets the mimetype from the filename, coudl be much better, this should help you.

```
Private Sub ShowDocument(fileName As String, fileContent As Byte())
    'Split the string by character . to get file extension type
    Dim stringParts As String() = fileName.Split(New Char() {"."C})
    Dim strType As String = stringParts(1)
    Response.Clear()
    Response.ClearContent()
    Response.ClearHeaders()
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", Convert.ToString("attachment; filename=") & fileName)
    'Set the content type as file extension type
    Response.ContentType = strType
    'Write the file content
    Me.Response.BinaryWrite(fileContent)
    Me.Response.End()

End Sub
```

Comment: You shouldn't use String.Split to get the extension. Use System.IO.Path.GetExtension, stripping off the leading decimal. Also, the MimeType is not the same thing as a file extension. It should be something like "application/pdf".

Answer (score 0):

You might want something a bit more robust. Here's code that I've used when trying to send an arbitrary file to the browser. You should just have to call the WriteFile method, supplying your data. Note that the content type is up to you. We used "application/octet-stream" to force the browser to just want to save the file instead of opening it directly in the browser.

```
''' <summary>
''' Writes HTTP headers to support the transfer of a physical data file
''' </summary>
''' <param name="incomingFilename"></param>
''' <param name="fileLength"></param>
''' <param name="response"></param>
''' <param name="contentType"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Shared Sub WriteFileResponseHeaders(incomingFilename As String, fileLength As Integer?, response As System.Web.HttpResponse, contentType As String)
    For Each c As Char In System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars
        incomingFilename = incomingFilename.Replace(c, "-"c)
    Next

    'Strip disallowed characters from the filename
    Dim SafeName As String = incomingFilename
    Dim BadChars As String = "!@#$%^&*():<>?,/;"""

    For i As Integer = 0 To BadChars.Length - 1
        SafeName = SafeName.Replace(BadChars.Substring(i, 1), String.Empty)
    Next

    Dim EncodedUtf As String = "utf-8''"

    BadChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!#$&+=.^_'|~"

    For i As Integer = 0 To incomingFilename.Length - 1
        If BadChars.IndexOf(incomingFilename.Chars(i)) > -1 Then
            EncodedUtf &= incomingFilename.Chars(i)
        Else
            EncodedUtf &= "%" & AscW(incomingFilename.Chars(i)).ToString("x")
        End If
    Next

    With response
        .Clear()
        .ClearContent()
        .ClearHeaders()

        .AppendHeader("content-type", contentType)
        .AppendHeader("content-disposition",
                             String.Format("attachment; filename*={0}; size={1}; creation-date={2}; modification-date={2};read-date={2}; filename=""{3}""",
                                           EncodedUtf, If(fileLength.HasValue, fileLength, 0), Date.Now.ToString("R").Replace(",", " "), SafeName))


    End With
End Sub

Public Shared Sub WriteFile(fileData() As Byte, saveAs As String, response As System.Web.HttpResponse, contentType As String)
    WriteFileResponseHeaders(saveAs, fileData.Length, response, contentType)

    response.OutputStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length)
    response.Flush()
End Sub
```